# Unable to create Foreign Key (ERROR 1072)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a table which looks like this:

```
mysql>  SHOW COLUMNS FROM Users;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id    | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

I am trying to create a new table like this:

```
create table jobs (id int,  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But I am getting this error:

`ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table`

I am sure I am missing something very basic.

Comment: There isn't a column `user_id` in `jobs`...

Comment: shouldn't it be created as part of jobs table creation?

Comment: You're not creating it though, you need to specify the column name and data-type so that the foreign key has something to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
create table jobs (
    id int,  
    user_id int,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The first `user_id` in foreign key constraint refers to the table where the contraint is defined and the second refers to the table where it is pointing to.
So you need a field `user_id` in your jobs table, too.

Comment: MongoDB has spoiled me :) I was assuming MySQL will create key if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

This is the script you need:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    id int NOT NULL,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
)
```

Here's a good reference to learn the basics about setting up relationships: [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> You're trying to define as FOREIGN KEY, a column which is not present on your query.

That's the reason why you are receiving `Key column 'user_id' doesn't exist in table`

Observe your query:

```
 create table jobs (
 id int,
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

As the other answers have demonstrated:

> you have to define the creation of the column of your new table, which will be a FK for a PK from another table

```
 create table jobs (
 id int,
 user_id int NOT NULL
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id)
 ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table attendance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl_attendance
(
attendence_id INT(100) NOT NULL,
presence varchar(100) NOT NULL,
reason_id varchar(100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (attendance_id)
);
```

Comment: How is this table related to the question? OP was having issues adding a table **jobs** and have others like **Users** How is attendance related?